# JSON "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name."

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Getting an error in browser console, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'. Expected a property name.`. I'm simply trying/testing to log the json data.

```
$var = {{ json_encode($daily_clicks) }};
console.log($var);
```

**$daily_clicks** data being passed:

```
{
  "Feb 6, 2016": 0,
  "Feb 7, 2016": 0,
  "Feb 8, 2016": 7,
  "Feb 9, 2016": 5,
  "Feb 10, 2016": 0,
  "Feb 11, 2016": 0,
  "Feb 12, 2016": 0
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error?

In web console, data is being displayed as:

```
$var = {&quot;Feb 6, 2016&quot;:0,&quot;Feb 7, 2016&quot;:0,&quot;Feb 8, 2016&quot;:7,&quot;Feb 9, 2016&quot;:5,&quot;Feb 10, 2016&quot;:0,&quot;Feb 11, 2016&quot;:0,&quot;Feb 12, 2016&quot;:0};
```

Comment: Take a look at your page source.  Not the template, but the actual code that's being generated.  Make sure it looks correct.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Updated my question. Has to be the `&quot;`, right?

Comment: Looks like you're using htmlentities somewhere?

Comment: @MikeBarwick: That's the issue alright.

Comment: When you see the source of `$daily_clicks`, does it show the `&quot;` code? In other words, is it printing this way already from php, or just happens on the jquery side of your code?

Comment: Just the jQuery side of things...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a number of template languages, surrounding the identifier of a piece of data with `{{` and `}}` converts it to HTML.

The HTML special characters are invalid in that context in JavaScript.

You need to force whatever template language you are using (you didn't specify in the question) to output raw data.

Some templates which use that syntax use `{{{` and `}}}` for raw output.

Comment: Damn...rookie mistake. I'm using Laravel's template engine and yup - need to unescape the data. Agh! Haven't worked with much json data, that's not ajax. FIXED.

Comment: In Laravel's case, you can unescape data using `{!! .. !!}`